# Проблема в создании SQL триггера/процедуры

Tags: mysql, sql, триггер, процедуры

В общем. Есть запрос, который отлично работает в виде запроса, но когда я хочу его использовать в процедуре/триггере, то на него ругается MySQL
Запрос:

```
SET @d:= 0, @cf:=0, @ids:=0, @date:='01-01-2019', @user:=1098;

SELECT round(coeff/ids, 2) as sr_coeff, sum, us.current_bank, us.current_bank+((us.current_bank*sum)/100) as new_bank 
FROM ( SELECT @ids:=@ids+1 as ids, user, status, @cf:=@cf+coeff as coeff, if(status=1 and status!=3,@d:=@d+gb_percent,@d:=@d-gb_percent) as sum 
       FROM forecasts
       WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(date,'%d-%m-%Y') = @date and user = @user and status != 0 ORDER by ids DESC limit 1 ) t  
INNER JOIN users_stat_current_gb us on t.user = us.userID and us.date=@date
```

Comment: *на него ругается MySQL* Следует не жаловаться на ругань со стороны сервера, а цитировать сообщение об ошибке.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема может быть в символе, разделяющем команды. По умолчанию это точка с запятой. Но при определении хранимой процедуры или триггера точка с запятой в теле процедуры/триггера может сбить СУБД с толку. СУБД может "подумать", что определение окончилось некорректным образом. Поэтому надо изменить символ-разделитель на другой. Это делается командой `DELIMETER <новый_символ-разделитель>`. После определения процедуры/триггера надо вернуть разделитель по умолчанию командой `DELIMETER ;`. Подробнее читайте в документации к MySQL или ищите в любом поисковике по запросу "DELIMETER".

Comment: Весьма сомнительно. Скорее я поверю в то, что сервер отказывается использовать пользовательские переменные в этом контексте.

Comment: @yury-plinto Не работает это решение

Comment: @Akina, Как решить такую проблему тогда?